# Using Winform TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Is it good or bad practise to use tabs in winforms?

Do you need to preform anything specail to pass objects between them?

Comment: well, if you need tabs, you use a tab control, i dont see how that could be bad practice...

Comment: is it good or bad to drink a whisky ? I don't know, it depends how much, when and where, sometimes whith whom is important too...

Comment: This is not an issue of "good" or "bad" practice, not any more than is it "good" or "bad" practice to use a textbox. Moreover, there's no way to "pass objects between" tabs. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs are a suitable tool for grouping and organizing controls on a form.  They can help de-clutter a busy form.

You don't have to do anything special to pass data between controls on different tabs, as they're all on the same form.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to use multiple forms.

Comment: If you'd like the user to go through the tabs sequentially, then you can design the form to be a Wizard form, but otherwise tabbed forms are good for roles such as a Settings form.

Comment: No don't need them to be sequental, can either copy and extract (those as the two tabs) or just do one. The tabs are purly to declutter the form

Comment: That sounds like a great case for using Tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tab Control. Its totally safe.

You do not need anything special to pass value between tabs.

They are used when you want to open multiple forms in a single control that is your tabcontrol.

Those forms can be opened as Child/Content in Tab items. Each and every one of them will maintain its state and value even if you switch from one tab to another.

Comment: Yes, everything Microsoft provides is good, like manna that falls from heaven. If you're going to post an answer, at least explain in what cases a tab control might be suitable or desired.

Comment: Well that might not be true, but the point is taken. It has it's place.

Comment: @Brad: You on my side or Cody Gray side

Comment: I don't know about this 'sides' business. I didn't think it was downvote worthy. Especially since the original comment wasn't constructive itself. But, the comment and the answer are both better now so all's well!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement, Tabs are good to group related controls, but sometimes it does not provide a very good user experience by hiding out some controls.

You don have to do any thing to pass information in between them and you can access any control with in a tab, and controls in any tab can access from variables in which they are hosted.

Answer (score 1):

TabControl is a good control if you want to sort and avoid multiples new forms. If you want to pass data between tabs, there's no problem because it's one control for multiple tabs.